# Image processing in headless mode

Tags: image-transforms, headless

How to do image processing & transformations when not using templates?

I'm using react-static for the frontend.

Is it possible to have CraftCMS process the images upon upload?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Imager Pre-transform plugin](https://github.com/superbigco/craft-imagerpretransform/blob/master/README.md), or I can recommend a service like https://www.imgix.com where you can perform transforms using url parameters.